# Extracting dicom headers in R

Tags: r, dicom

I'm trying to use this dataset here

https://mri.radiology.uiowa.edu/VHDicom/VHMCT1mm/VHMCT1mm_Head.tar.gz

to test out the `oro.dicom` package in R.

I try out the code

```
dcmImages <- readDICOM("C:\\Users\\Host\\Documents\\SCANS\\Head", verbose = TRUE,
                       recursive = TRUE)
```

then I try out the `extractHeader` function like this

```
extractHeader(dcmImages$hdr, string="InstitutionName")
```

and I get a bunch of `NA`'s. However, I can clearly see when I run this

```
dcmImages$hdr
```

I can see in the console that institution name is listed as the National Library of Medicine. What is causing the discrepancy?

Update: Eventually the answer below started working but previously it wasn't and I'm not sure why. I'm on Windows 10 OS and I updated R from 3.5.3 to 3.6 and then it started working but this error that says `signed = FALSE' is only valid for integers of sizes 1 and 2'` persists when running the `readDICOM` function. However, I now have output from the headers instead of `NA`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
library(oro.dicom)
dcmImages <- readDICOM("/<my path>/Head", verbose = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
extractHeader(dcmImages$hdr, string="InstitutionName", numeric=FALSE)
```

(The default for numeric is TRUE, and values are converted to numbers when TRUE.)

```
R> extractHeader(dcmImages$hdr, string="InstitutionName", numeric=FALSE)
  [1] "National Library of Medicine" "National Library of Medicine" "National Library of Medicine"
  [4] "National Library of Medicine" "National Library of Medicine" "National Library of Medicine"
  [7] "National Library of Medicine" "National Library of Medicine" "National Library of Medicine"
 [10] "National Library of Medicine" "National Library of Medicine" "National Library of Medicine"
```

Comment: Hmm the result I get is again `NA`s when I do this

Comment: That's strange...I downloaded the images from uiowa and it seems to work fine --- see edited answer above.

Comment: Are you on a Windows or Mac/Unix-like OS?

Comment: I'm using Mac OS

Comment: I see. I'm on Windows. Wondering if it means something. Did you get this warning when you ran the code? `signed = FALSE' is only valid for integers of sizes 1 and 2'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195763/discussion-between-ben-and-762).